# Problem routing traffic to AWS elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

In my AWS environment I have 2 hosted zones:

- aaa.nl
- bbb.nl

I have an elastic beanstalk (NodeJS) application running. It works fine. I want this EB application to be available via the domain name:

- my-app.bbb.nl

I followed this approach:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-alias-procedure

Configuring a new record is easy. I can select my EB application and the record is created successfully. And i see it listed in the record list of hosted zone bbb.nl (A Record)

Now I open up my browser and navigate to:

- my-app.bbb.nl

To my great surprise, what I get to see in the browser is a different application that I have running at https://my-other-app.aaa.nl, but the url is https://app.bbb.nl (my-other-app is listed as an A record in hosted zone aaa.nl)

- I did get some certificate warnings in my browser as well (in the browser I see that it has the ssl certificate of aaa.nl coming along),
- I do have something else running correctly at https://bbb.nl

I have no idea how this is possible and how to debug this. Anyone any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Use browser development tools to trace the request to `my-app.bbb.nl`
Look for redirection in response.
Check if `my-other-app.aaa.nl` isn't hardcoded into app itself.

Comment: There is no redirect, i see a straight http 200 response in the browser network log